# Java scanner delimiter causes my integer to not be read properly

Tags: java, delimiter

So I'm creating a scanner to read off of a simple text file:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Weather {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        int a;
        
        File weatherData = new File("C:\\Users\\taddi\\eclipse-workspace\\COS_160_ASSIGNMENT_10\\src\\PortlandWeather1941to2018.txt");

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(weatherData);
        scnr.useDelimiter("//");
        
        int totalCount = scnr.nextInt();// this reads the number at the beginning and uses it so I know how many times to run the loop
        String throwAway1 = scnr.nextLine();//these statement are used to throw a way the rest of line 1, and all of line 2 and 3
        String throwAway2 = scnr.nextLine();
        String throwAway3 = scnr.nextLine();
        
        int[] month = new int[totalCount];
        int[] day = new int[totalCount];
        int[] year = new int[totalCount];
        
        int[] tmax = new int[totalCount];
        int[] tmin = new int[totalCount];
        
        for(a = 0; a < totalCount; a ++) {
            month[a] = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println(month[a]);
             day[a] = scnr.nextInt();
             System.out.println(day[a]);
            year[a] = scnr.nextInt();
            
            tmax[a] = scnr.nextInt();
            tmin[a] = scnr.nextInt();
        }
    }

}
```

The first part of the text file is an integer I'm trying to read. For some reason, it only reads that integer when I comment out the scnr.useDelimiter("//"); line, otherwise I get an InputMismatchException
I'd love to just get rid of all the unnecessary words and slashes in the text file but that wouldn't satisfy the assignment. What's going wrong with the delimiter? How do I read the integer?

Comment: Please include the contents of the text file in the question

Comment: You might want `"[/\\s]+"` as your delimiter - either a slash (which you shouldn't double up) or whitespace.  And the `+` means you'll match one or more such characters.

Comment: Alright here's the content of the text file for the first few lines, there are thousands of lines it but they all follow the same format: 28489 data records
DATE       TMAX TMIN
---------- ---- ----
01/01/1941   38   25
01/02/1941   32   20
01/03/1941   31   22
01/04/1941   34   25

Comment: A) dont put additional content into comments, always update your QUESTION instead. And B) dont START with content that comes from a FILE. First, just HARDCODE some "lines" directly in your code. That way, you can test things much easier, and it is much easier to share your code with us. Because we could run it as is, not needing your file!

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter is a `string`, and it will not work in your use case the way you want.

I assume your sample data is like this (ignoring the header lines) ...

```
01/01/1941 38 25
01/02/1941 32 20
```

... so you are looking to get each number - the date elements and the tmax/tmin values - so a single delimiter character of '/' would only break up the date.

For example:

```
        final String data = 
"01/01/1941 38 25 \n"+
"01/02/1941 32 20 \n";
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(data);
        scnr.useDelimiter("/");

        while(scnr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scnr.next());
        }
        scnr.close();
```

outputs the following ...

```
01
01
1941 38 25
01
02
1941 32 20
```

showing that it splits on the date d/m/y slashes, but the year and tmax and tmin are bundled together.

Adjusting the scanner to use a `Pattern` delimiter allows us to split on the slashes *and* the spaces.

```
        final String data = 
"01/01/1941 38 25 \n"+
"01/02/1941 32 20 \n";
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(data);
        scnr.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[/ ]+"));

        while(scnr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scnr.next());
        }
        scnr.close();
    }
```

giving the output I think you want:

```
01
01
1941
38
25

01
02
1941
32
20
```

However, note that in my example data I have trailing whitespace on each line and they are thus also returned as empty String tokens. If I was scanning for `nextInt()` I would get an `java.util.InputMismatchException` error. Depending on the exact formatting of your input you may need to cater for that.